# Return active FCurve with python

Tags: python, animation, fcurves

i'm trying to write a little addon to help deal with FCurves modifier, and i would need to get the active modifier from active FCurves.

So far i'm not able to return active FCurve in python, i don't really know where to look. The purpose being get the active modifier in this FCurve, i tried to just iterate and get modifier marked as active, but they can be several (one by FCurves) so it won't work as intented.
I can only get selected FCurves with

```
fcurves[index].select
```

Do you have any idea where to look for this property ? Cheers guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i finally found it, you have to call

```
bpy.context.active_editable_fcurve
```

from graph_editor context, active F Curve doesn’t seem to exist as a property out of context afaik !